# Infinite redirect loop

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have to finish somebody else project but I have an issue on invalid requests:

If I put this url it works:

```
http://localhost/Files/pictures/thumbs/28967579qwR.jpg_2014-03-11%2014-13-53.jpg
```

With this one, I have infinite loops (the file doesn't exists):

```
http://localhost/Files/pictures/thumbs/s28967579qwR.jpg_2014-03-11%2014-13-53.jpg
```

With this one, I have no redirect loops but I am asking a non existing file:

```
http://localhost/home/sd.jpg
```

In the .htaccess I have this:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

My index.php file:

```
<?php

/*
 * Url friendly base
 */

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
error_log($url);
if (isset($url)) {
    $links = explode('/', $url);
    //voler minuscula
    $link = strtolower($links[1]);
    switch ($link) {

        case 'join':
            include_once 'frontend/join.php';
            break;

        case 'join-video':
            include_once 'frontend/join-video.php';
            break;

        case 'hd-movies':
            include_once 'frontend/hd-movies.php';
            break;

        case 'contact':
            include_once 'frontend/contact.php';
            break;

        case 'login':
            include_once 'frontend/login.php';
            break;

        case 'model':
            include_once 'frontend/model.php';
            break;

        case 'our-models':
            include_once 'frontend/our-models.php';
            break;

        case 'recherche':
            include_once 'frontend/resultat-recherche.php';
            break;

        case 'video':
            include_once 'frontend/video.php';
            break;
        case 'update':
            include_once 'frontend/updates.php';
            break;

        case 'home':
            include_once 'frontend/index.php';
            break;
        default:
            header('Location: home/');
            // include_once 'frontend/index.php';
            break;
    }
}
?>
```

Do you have any idea why this happens on some files and not others and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any `files` case in your switch, where is it going when you're calling top links from your question ?

Comment: As far as I can see, you're redirecting to home/ in both cases. I guess what's in home/ redirects you again... Can you post the code whihc is there?

Comment: @JustinIurman it will just use the default case since there is no match.

Comment: @PanamaJack Well yes, this is what i was pointing. And to me, it does not make sense regarding on the question and the links OP tried to access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid infinite loops I finally decided to use sessions at this:

```
    <?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['redirect_uri'])) {
    $_SESSION['redirect_uri'] = 0;
}

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (isset($url)) {
$links = explode('/', $url);
//voler minuscula
$link = strtolower($links[1]);
switch ($link) {

    case 'join':
        include_once 'frontend/join.php';
        break;

    case 'join-video':
        include_once 'frontend/join-video.php';
        break;

    case 'hd-movies':
        include_once 'frontend/hd-movies.php';
        break;

    case 'contact':
        include_once 'frontend/contact.php';
        break;

    case 'login':
        include_once 'frontend/login.php';
        break;

    case 'model':
        include_once 'frontend/model.php';
        break;

    case 'our-models':
        include_once 'frontend/our-models.php';
        break;

    case 'recherche':
        include_once 'frontend/resultat-recherche.php';
        break;

    case 'video':
        include_once 'frontend/video.php';
        break;

    case 'update':
        include_once 'frontend/updates.php';
        break;

    case 'home':
        include_once 'frontend/index.php';
        break;

    default:
        // This will avoid redirect loop
        $_SESSION['redirect_uri']++;
        if ($_SESSION['redirect_uri'] < 1 ) {
            header('Location: home/');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['redirect_uri'] = 0;
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        }
        break;
}
```

}
?>